# My Indian passport doesn't contain a postcode. Can I still apply for a Schengen visa?

Tags: visas, passports, indian-citizens, paperwork, poland

I am planning to move to Poland. My passport doesn't have a post code in the address. Will that be of any issue with my visa application?

Comment: Passports don't have PINs, even ones with a chip in them. Do you mean _postcode_? That should not be a problem; EU passports don't include the holder's _address_ in the first place, so Polish officials will not know anything is missing.

Comment: Thanks Henning. But in the visa application I have mentioned the complete address with the postcode.

Comment: Schengen visa does not require you to produce any proof of your current address. You just have to mention your current address. It can even be different than the one printed on your passport. The absence of postcode on your passport does not matter at all.

Comment: Thanks @RedBaron. But I am applying for national Visa.

Comment: AFAIK its the same for Type-D visas. The address on your passport is not used for visas because many countries do not provide such information on the passport. Even Indian govt. was about to remove the last page of the passport but changed its mind at the last moment. If the embassy does need a proof of your current address, you will find such a requirement mentioned in the [document checklist](http://www.mumbai.mfa.gov.pl/resource/84e2939e-c376-4d76-8664-891085a0e15c:JCR).

Comment: Note that the converse also applies, your passport wouldn't be considered proof of address in Europe, since there's no indication of whether it's been kept up to date.

Comment: @origimbo Do they don't consider passport as proof of address of anyone or would it be just for my case as it don't have a post code?

Comment: Not for anyone. Generically in Europe "proof of address" would mean something like a current rental agreement, or a (recent) utility bill, although there may be other options in specific countries, depending on registration requirements.

Comment: USA passports have a place for the bearer to fill in his or her address; it is not required for validity, and at the time of my life when I moved often, I used pencil. There is no problem here.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever is written in your Indian passport is not a problem. Simply write the postal code of wherever you currently live (I presume it has one assigned by the postal service) and apply for the visa.